# White Space in MS chart

Tags: c#, mschart

[image]I have a simple chart with 12 data points. The problem is that it shows a little white area before starting the trend lines.
Here is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], plotDataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], plotDataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
    chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
    chart1.Series[3].Points.AddXY(DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], DataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[4]);
}
```

First column of DataTable is string and the other four are floats.

Comment: a picture will say more than a thousand words. And for anybody to reproduce, we will need the chart properties (series configuration, ...)

Comment: sorry for the miss.

Comment: where's the white area in your image? im seeing lots of white areas. :D maybe try encircling it? ever tried snipping tool?

Comment: some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12839421/1132334, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9d8e04e-2f30-4cdb-8a17-9f520e3b4d91/can-i-control-the-chart-padding-?forum=MSWinWebChart

Comment: [not a perfect duplicate, but related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2291090/1132334)

Comment: I missed the point about adding string as x-values, which is not recommended; see my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `AxisX.Minimum` to a suitable value.

Usually this would be `0` or the x-value of the **first** `DataPoint`.

But the way you add the values this will not work.

You are adding the `DataPoints` in a rather unfortunte way, which sometimes is ok, but more often than not it will create all sorts of problems.

The recommended way is to add the x-values as **numbers**, or `DateTimes`, which internally will be converted to `doubles`.

But you add `strings`. This **looks** ok but the x-values contain neither those strings not anything else but `0s`. Threfore you can't use them to set the range or tooltips or zoom ranges or to calculate stuff..

But if you want to you can still get the result you want by setting the minimum to `1`:

```
ChartArea ca = yourChart.ChartAreas[0];
ca.AxisX.Minimum = 1;
```

[image]

I have added my x-values as string, too, but they look like numbers.

But the **recommended** way would be to convert your values to numbers so you can use them for all sorts of things..

A few notes:

- This conversion is done by the chart, if at all possible for the **y-values but not for the x-values**! Maybe because a chart without numeric y-values makes no sense at all while sometimes x-values simply do not contain meaningful numeric data, like names, IDs, zip codes etc..
- Don't let the visuals fool you: The `strings` are only copied into the axis labels; otherwise they are **lost**! (You should check this with the debugger!!)
- You may notice that the number of Label changes in the screenshot. The number is calculated from the `Interval` of  the x-axis. By default it is calculated  automatically (`Interval=double.NaN`)to fit in a reasonable number. You can set it to any distance you like. Normaly it refers to the axis unit  but in this case to the number of points. Set it to `2` to get one `Label` for every 2nd point; set it to `0.5` to get 2 `Labels` per `DataPoint`..
- With real numbers (or DataTimes) as x-values you can also set a type for the interval like seconds or days..

Comment: can i increase the number of x-axis labels?

Comment: I have changed the type of the points to be added to series like this:

Comment: string time=plotDataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim();
                        
DateTime dTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        chart_GraphicalTrendsChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dTime, float value);

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ChartArea's IsStartedFromZero property is set true.  This setting will force the chart to always start from zero.  Try setting it to false:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
```

Comment: Good idea! But as I have explained all x-values are `0` so this doesn't work here.